# Apache HttpClient: Limit total calls per second

Tags: java, httpclient, metering

I need to limit the number of HTTP calls per second to max 10. This is as per the allowed quota.

Does HttpClient has some feature for this? Or any custom implementation would also do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try the [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html).

From the javadoc:

> A ThreadPoolExecutor that can additionally schedule commands to run
>   after a given delay, or to execute periodically

You would simply use the [`schedule`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#schedule(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method and pass it a `Runnable`, where the `Runnable` makes your call via the `HttpClient`. You could schedule your `Runnable` to run 10 times per second, or as needed. The `Executor` will queue up your calls over the `HttpClient`, and only run a max of 10 per second.

Comment: HTTP calls in my scenario can't be concurrent. They all need to be in series one after the another. Using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor will run different threads parallelly.

Comment: set the [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor(int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue)) argument `maxPoolSize` to one. There will be no concurrent threads. Alternately call [setMaxPoolSize()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setMaximumPoolSize(int)).